# Mouse event Button onclick need to be run escape keycode = 27

Tags: javascript, html, css

When Mouse event Button onclick  need to be run escape keycode = 27,

```js
Brav1Toolbox.addListener(window, "keyup", onKeyUp);
function onKeyUp(e) {
//code
 switch (e.keyCode) {
          case 27 : // esc
            _toggleOverview(true);
            break;
          case 33 : // pag up
          //code
          }
}
```

Above is esc key press function, I need to mouse down event the same function

```js
function change_screen(e){
  if(e==27){
    //keycode = 27 is clicked
  }
}
```

```html
<div onclick="change_screen(27)" class="b1">Click</div>
```

It is possible to run, kindly suggest

Comment: I don't get what you're asking... When clicking the mouse there is no keycode...

Comment: what is `change_screen` function? you havne't shown it

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to understand the question but:

If you had a `keyup` and `keydown` listener then you could set an `isEscapePressed` variable based on the state of the escape key.  You could then use that variable inside the mouse event listener.

Comment: This should be a comment at best, how can you answer a question you do not understand?

Comment: @KobyDouek Because I think I do understand it. If OP clarifies and I'm wrong then I'll delete the answer.